# Selecting Variable Dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello and thank you for your time.  Im fairly new to IOS/Objective C.

I have multiple variables setup globally at the top of my viewcontroller.

```
NSMutableArray * A;
NSMutableArray * B;
NSMutableArray * C;
```

Now when someone selects a cell in a tableview I would like to use the name of that cell to select one of the global variables.  I found something for doing this with viewcontrollers, but I need something for misc variables as well.  I am reffering to:

```
id myNewController = [[NSClassFromString(selected) alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myNewController animated:YES];
```

So it would be something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Save text of the selected cell:
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
stringVariable = cell.textLabel.text;// value=A,B or C

// match string to array and load that array.
??         

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help, and sorry if this has been asked but I couldn't find anything that worked so as a last resort im asking for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off storing your arrays as keys on a dictionary, instead of as individual fields. For example:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary;

dictionary = @{
    @"A": [[NSMutableArray alloc] init],
    @"B": [[NSMutableArray alloc] init],
    @"C": [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
};
```

Then when your row is selected, you could lookup the array by key:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString* key = cell.textLabel.text;// value=A,B or C

NSMutableArray* array = dictionary[key];
....
```

Comment: Seems like a viable solution.  Ive seen that before I just needed it simplified so I could grasp it.  I'm going to try and impliment it and if it meets my expectations I will rate you up.  Thanks for the help bendytree :)

Comment: This led me down the right path, the only thing I needed to do was change the way I was initializing the dictionary.

I needed to add existing arrays to the dictionary, and then pass them to the event handler like so
   
    dictionary= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:A forKey:@"A"];

that did the trick fr me, thanks!